# laurent series convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent Series representations in powers of $z$ for

i) $\frac{ \cos{z}}{z}$

ii) $z^4 \cosh{\frac{1}{z^2}}$

Where do they converge?

I found the Laurent Series for each of the functions, yielding the result

i) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$

ii) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^4}{(2n)!(z^2)^{2n}}$

Both of these functions have a pole at $z=0$, so I want to say that the answer to where they converge is $z \neq 0$.  However, I am under the impression that a Laurent series should have a convergence along the lines of $r< |z-z_0| < R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $z_0:=0$ giving $$r< |z-0| < R$$ or $$r< |z| < R$$ for the desired set of convergence.

Comment: Yes, but what is $r$ and $R$?  That is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @Snagglewhen $r$ and $R$ are just any positive real numbers: $0<r<R$.

Comment: Yes, but in this particular case?  Is what I assumed above true and the series converges for $z \neq 0$?   In that case, how would I represent that in the above form?  I could say that it converges for $0 < |z| < \infty$.

Comment: @Snagglewhen Yes, you can say it like this:the Laurent series is convergent on the set $0 < |z| < \infty$. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  I was simply trying to make sure that I was not mistaken.